# Hide a button on click outside

Tags: jquery, html, button

I am not sure how to do this since I am a newbie. I need a dropwdown menu `.dmenu` when clicked a button `.dropB` and need that `.dmenu` to `hide` as soon as the button is cliked or clicked anywhere outside the button.

```
$('.dropB').click(function(){
      $('.dmenu').toggle();
})
```

But this does not allows it to hide when clicked anywhere outside the `.dropB`.
Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you define "clicked outside `.dropB`? can you share the markup maybe create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.dropB').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.dmenu').toggle();
})

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.dmenu')) {
        $('.dmenu').hide();
    }
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8V8n/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use delegation to handle clicks on document. Check the target, if it matches your button then `toggle` the menu. If not, then `hide` the menu.

***Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ztxa2/**

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass("dropB")) {
        $('.dmenu').toggle();
    } else {
        if (! $target.hasClass("dmenu")) {
            $('.dmenu').hide();
        }
    }
})
```

You may also want to check if the target is the *menu* itself, so as not to hide itself when clicked.

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Fixed @Liam. Old habit!

Comment: You may want to use stopPropogation() as click on menu is also a click on document.

Comment: @Pazza22: I wrote that in the answer itself thinking the Op could take it up from there.

Comment: @user3187838: Added fiddle.